# Call an external API upon new user creation

Tags: rest-api, external-app, trigggers

Is there a way to call an external REST API from Salesforce once a new user (customer) has been created in the system?

This should be an automatic process and the API will be called right after the new user has been created in Salesforce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can write an [after insert trigger](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) and flow will be like this

   1. Trigger on User(after insert)
   2. Asynchronous function call (@future annotation)
   3. HttpRequest/HttpResponse -> (Optional) Update user details in external system with passed data.
2. If you can use SOAP notifications, you can just visit Setup > Create > Workflow & Approvals > Workflow Rules/Outbound Messages (you'll need one of each). This is a built-in way to send notifications to external systems without writing code in salesforce.com at all (you'll need a SOAP endpoint configured with the WSDL from the Outbound Message, though). It might be easier to take this route in terms of development time, if you or someone you know is more competent in PHP, .NET, etc than in Apex Code.

Comment: note also governor limits if doing batch load of Users; one also probably wants to think through what happens in sandbox when users are added there